# Невидимый слой, блокирующий запрос

Tags: django, bootstrap, http, webbrowser

### Кривые руки или отсутствие знаний?

Вопрос нетривиальный, так как похожих ситуаций гугл, яндекс и so мне не выдал, вопросы ставил по-разному. Вот и пишу сей вопрос...

С bootstrap я стал знакомиться недавно. (Версия django 2.0a1, bootstrap4 из стандартных ссылок CDN) Из приложенных ниже скриншотов видно, что по всем кнопкам, кроме "Home", реквест проходит, хотя по корзине и не должен 乁( ⁰͡  Ĺ̯ ⁰͡ ) ㄏ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию же из url.com/goods по кнопке "Home" у нас лишь срабатывает js от bootstrap, а сама страница не открывается, http реквест просто не происходит.

Подскажите, где я накосячил, может, подскажете материал к чтению, чтоб подобных перлов не было?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы был переход на страницу home, в ссылке на эту страницу надо указывать не якорь - "#", а именно путь до этой страницы. Вы же получается используете [якорь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya), который действует внутри этой страницы, и не ведет на другие.

Comment: Да, но если убрать якорь и прописать "/home" ситуация не меняется, запрос не уходит со страницы и он не грузит ничего =/

Comment: Нужно ссылку указать `/`, а не `/home`

Comment: EgorSmolyakov, без разницы. http запрос не уходит с сайта. Хоть что впиши в href, GET не отправляется, лишь отрабатывает js. Это как-то связано с data атрибутами я думаю =(